# Canonical morphism in Huybrecht's Fourier-Mukai Transformations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

Let $(\mathcal{D},T)$ be a $k$-linear triangulated category and
$A, E \in \mathcal{D}$. Define as $A[i]:= T^i(A) $ the $i$-th twist
under endomorphism $T: \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{D}$.

In the proof of lemma 1.58 in Huybrecht's Fourier-Mukai Transformations
in Algebraic Geometry I one consider the *canonical morphism*

$$  \bigoplus \operatorname{Hom}(E, A[i]) \otimes E[-i] \to A      $$

I would like to clarify how this morphism arises canonically in detail.
That looks structurally rather similar to canonical evauation morphism
$\operatorname{Hom}(A, B) \otimes A \to B$, but the twist on $E$
by $-i$ in the right argument prevents it from beeing adaptable
for the evaluation map. So how is each map $\operatorname{Hom}(E, A[i]) \otimes E[-i] \to A$ canonically defined?

Comment: Apply $ T^{-i} $ to the first factor in the tensor product to land up in your situation, where it’s evaluation.